# How can I listen for changes in one plot's traits and update the second by that amount?

Tags: python, events, traits, enthought, chaco

https://github.com/enthought/chaco/blob/master/examples/demo/edit_line.py

My desired result is to have two plots side-by-side, the left is this `edit_line.py` plot, the right displays the sum of the y-values in `edit_line.py` and another array.

Right now I can look at `self.component.index` and `self.component.value` (x and y, respectively) from within `PointDraggingTool`. However, I need to be able to update the second plot based on updates in the first. How would I listen for changes in the first plot's traits and update the second by that amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out -- I'll post a proper solution soon.

In summary, it required listening to updates of the first plot using `on_trait_change(self.lineplot.value, self._handle_data_change, name="data_changed")` and redrawing the second plot